# In an irreducible, aperiodic, null-recurrent Markov chain holds $\sum_n p_{ij}^{(n)} = \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, divergent-series

My lecture notes state the following theorem:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $(X_n)$ be an irreducible, aperiodic, null-recurrent Markov chain. Then $$\forall i,j \in S : p_{ij}^{(n)}\to 0 \text{ and } \sum_n p_{ij}^{(n)} = \infty$$

And the proof starts like this

> The divergence of the series $\color{red}{\text{follows}}$ from the Theorem 1, so we just need to show $p_{ij}^{(n)}\to 0$.

Okay, I go to the theorem 1 and see roughly the following:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain.
>
> - If $i\in S$ is recurrent then $\sum_n p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$.
> - If $i\in S$ is transient then $\sum_n p_{ii}^{(n)} < \infty$.

I tried to figure out why would it follow by trying to come up with an inequality like $$p_{ii}^{(n+m+k)}\geq p_{ij}^{(n)} p_{jj}^{(m)} p_{ji}^{(k)}$$
yet it didn't help.

In other sources, it seems to be a non-trivial result which is proven with Abel's lemma.

So my question is: can the divergence of the series in theorem 2 be followed from theorem 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the Markov chain is irreducible, it is possible to get from state $i$ to state $j$, so $p_{ij}^{(k)} > 0$ for some $k$.  Then $p_{ij}^{(n+k)} \ge p_{ii}^{(n)} p_{ij}^{(k)}$, so $$\sum_{n\ge 0} p_{ij}^{(n)} \ge \sum_{n\ge k} p_{ij}^{(n)} = \sum_{n\ge 0} p_{ij}^{(n+k)}\ge p_{ij}^{(k)} \sum_{n \ge 0} p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$$

Comment: As $\sum_nP_{ii}^{(n)}=\infty ,$ then tha Markov chain is recurrent, Am I correct?